# Как убрать окружность на конце линии при значении атрибута stroke-linecap="round "

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox, svg-animation

Я написал простой пример прогресс-бара, чтобы продемонстрировать проблему:

Ниже на изображении маленький кружок на конце линии перед началом анимации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Анимация начинается после клика по холсту SVG:*

```html
<style>
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;background:silver;}
svg{width:30%;}
</style>

<svg id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="8"/>
  <path id="progress" stroke-dasharray="251.2" stroke-dashoffset="251.2" stroke-width="8" stroke="#4596AB" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"> 
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="251.2;0;251.2" fill="freeze" />     
  </path>
</svg>
```

Когда я назначаю атрибут `stroke-linecap = "round"`, в начале строки появляется круг. В этом случае линия имеет нулевую длину.

С другими значениями, например, `stroke-linecap = "butt"`, этого эффекта не будет.

Как удалить кружок в начале строки с помощью stroke-linecap = "round"?

**Примечание:** Этот эффект не наблюдается здесь во фрагменте, но отчетливо виден в браузере в отдельно сохраненном файле. Как показано на рисунке выше.

Comment: @MaximLensky да, спасибо, неточность, исправил. Но сейчас браузеры это переваривают и на результат это не повлияло. Тут причина в другом

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yxego6wn/ Хак конечно так себе... но может поможет)

Comment: @DiD Спасибо! Работает. Интересная мысль, разделить на 2 анимации. Если сможете обосновать, как работает, хорошо бы оформить ответом здесь

Comment: Да две анимации - это обычная штука. Для меня там самый непонятный факт заключается в том, почему одинаковая анимация с положительным знаком оставляет кружок и такая же анимация с отрицательным знаком (то есть в другую сторону) не оставляет кружка.

Comment: Я не претендую на ответ, и даже не до конца понимаю, почему оно так работает. Это просто удачное стечение обстоятельств навеяло попробовать пошевелить значения разными вариантами изменений. Так что результат получился чисто случайностью. А тот факт из предыдущего комментария теперь долго будет мучать бессонницей.

Comment: @DiD так и в моем ответе осталась загадка, почему второй знак после запятой в stroke-dashoffset и stroke-dasharray убирает этот круг. И ещё, попробуйте stroke-linecap="round" при stroke-dasharray="0 100" Вроде здесь длина черточки равна нулю, а пробел равен 100.  И окружность будет  заполнена кружочками.  Вот здесь я исследовал это http://svg-art.ru/?p=1979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина этой ошибки браузера была обнаружена с помощью [**@Paul LeBeau**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)

Я посчитал длину окружности в вопросе `2 * PI * 40 ~= 2 * 3,14 * 40 ~= 251,2`

При этом значении `251,2` есть маленький кружок, как показано на картинке в вопросе.

Если вы рассчитываете с помощью `getTotalLength()`, вы получаете `251.36264038085938`
При этом значении длины окружности `~= 251,36` маленького кружка нет

```html
<style>
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;background:silver;}
svg{width:30%;}
</style>

<svg id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="8"/>
  <path id="progress" stroke-dasharray="251.36" stroke-dashoffset="251.36" stroke-width="8" stroke="#4596AB" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"> 
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="251.36;0;251.36" fill="freeze" />       
  </path>
</svg>
<script>
 console.log(progress.getTotalLength());
 </script>
```

**Вывод:** чтобы не было маленького кружка, нужно считать длину окружности до второго знака после запятой.